# Restart idmapd without rebooting the host?

Tags: linux, centos, nfs4

When I have changed `Domain` in `/etc/idmapd.conf` and then `service idmapd restart`, then the change doesn't take effect until I `reboot`.

Is it possible to do this without having to rebooting the host?

I have the problem on CentOS 6.

Comment: On CentOS 6 it's service rpcidmapd

Comment: or 'nfsidmap -c' to clean up kernel cache

Answer (score 2):

service is responsible for that is: `rpc.idmapd - NFSv4 ID <-> Name Mapper` and to restart it you should be using:

```
service rpcidmapd status
```

Answer (score 2):

The fix may require less than this, but this should work:

```
service rpcbind restart
service rpcidmapd restart
service nfslock restart
service netfs restart
service nfs restart
```